# Audio in Java Applet not playing

Tags: java, applet, audio

I  am trying to play audio in a Java applet but it is not working. What could be the problem?

EDIT: Besides the limited number of files that Java can play, the problem was that I didn't realize that the bin folder (in Eclipse workspace) contains the .class file that is run. So my code referring to the getDocumentBase() couldn't find the audio file. -_-"

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Viewer extends Applet
    implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    AudioClip sound1;
    AudioClip tap;
    AudioClip clap;

    public void init() {
        sound1 = this.getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(),"boom.au");
        tap = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "tap.au");
        clap = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "clap.au");

        this.resize(600,600);

        addMouseListener(this);

        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g) {

    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        sound1.play();
        System.out.println("BOOM!");
    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        tap.play();
        System.out.println("tap!");
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) { }
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) { }

}
```

Comment: What messages, complaints, or Exceptions do you get?

Comment: +1 happened to me yesterday too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Besides the limited number of files that Java can play, the problem was that I didn't realize that the bin folder (in Eclipse workspace) contains the .class file that is run. So my code referring to the getDocumentBase() couldn't find the audio file. -_-"

Answer (score 3):

It appears that Sun's applet implementation is very choosy about exactly what sounds formats it will play. Specifically ["Currently, the Java [applet] API supports only one sound format: 8 bit, µ-law, 8000 Hz, one-channel, Sun ".au" files."](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/applet/sound.html)

Answer (score 1):

If it's the problem mentioned by Tom (quite probably), use the JavaSound API to play your audio.